# I cant add row in my Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to build a CMS for my portfolio site. I created all the forms in the back end. Everything works except I cant add a column in my portfolio database in Mysqli. I have tried to echo the form data in another PHP page. Everything works fine. Even the uploaded image is moved to site directory. The only problem is Inserting the data in the Database Table. Here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];
    $duration=$_POST['duration'];
    $category=$_POST['category'];

    $nImage=$_FILES['nImage']['name'];
    $file_tmp=$_FILES['nImage']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize=$_FILES['nImage']['size'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(pathinfo($nImage,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $supported=array('jpg','jpeg','png');

    //Rename File
    $rand=sha1(time());
    $newname=$rand.".".$file_ext;
    $portfolio_img_dir="images/portfolio/".$newname;

    //Check If FileSize is more than 2 MB
    if($filesize<2097152)
    {

        //Check if Extension Matches
        if(in_array($file_ext,$supported))
        {
            //Move Uploaded Image
            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$portfolio_img_dir))
            {
                $qry=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `p_o_r_t_f_o_l_i_o`(`title`,`description`,`duration`,`category`,`image`) values('$title','$description','$duration','$category','$portfolio_img_dir')");

                    if($qry)
                    {

                        $_SESSION['add_port_msg_success']="Portfolio Item Successfully Added";
                        header('location:add_portfolio.php');

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION['add_portfolio_msg']="Portfolio Item Failed to Add";
                        header('location:add_portfolio.php');
                    }

            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['add_port_msg']="File Failed to Move";
                header('location:add_portfolio.php');
            }
        }

        else
        {
            $_SESSION['add_port_msg']="File Extension not Supported";
            header('location:add_portfolio.php');
        }

    }

    else
    {
        $_SESSION['add_port_msg']="Filesize too Large";
        header('location:add_portfolio.php');
    }

}

else
{
    $_SESSION['add_port_msg']="Invalid Attempt to Access Page";
    header('location:add_portfolio.php');
}
?>
```

and this is my HTML FORM

```
<!--Add New Portfolio Item Form-->
                <div class='col-md-8 col-offset-4'>
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="act_newp.php">
                    <fieldset>

                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <legend>Add New Portfolio Item</legend>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Item Title</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                      <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter Title For the Item" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Textarea -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="description">Description</label>
                      <div class="col-md-4">                     
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="description">Enter Description of Portfolio Item</textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Multiple Radios -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="category">Select Category</label>
                         <div class="col-md-4">

                          <?php
                                $sel="SELECT cat_id,cat_name from categories order by  cat_name asc";
                                $query=mysqli_query($link,$sel);
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                                {

                                    echo "<div class='radio'>";
                                    echo "<label for='category-".$row['cat_id']."'>";
                                    echo "<input type='radio' name='category' value='".$row['cat_id']."'>";
                                    echo $row['cat_name'];
                                    echo "</label>";
                                    echo "</div>";

                                }                   
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="duration">Duration of Project</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                      <input name="duration" type="text" placeholder="Enter Duration in Hrs" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- File Button --> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nImage">File Button</label>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input name="nImage" class="input-file" type="file">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add New Portfolio Item</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                                    </div>
                <!--/Add New Portfolio Item Form Ends-->
```

here is my database table image :

[image: The first two are added by me from the Insert tab in Database menu]
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You're not only wide open to sql injection, it's very simple to inject you with bad files, too

Comment: To your question, do you have any error messages?

Comment: echo the insert query and try to directly execute from mysql(or phpMyAdmin) ...

Comment: Where are you creating the connection?

Comment: The Database is connected on the other file which is linked to the page. Database connection is not the problem....

Comment: I get no error messages but add_portfolio.php refreshes. This is the Add New Portfolio form page. @baao

Comment: You get no error messages because you don't check for them.

Answer (score 0):

To submit data from HTML `form`, you are using `button`, that clearly does not send `form` data,you have to use `input type="submit"`, so change this line of code

```
<button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add New Portfolio Item</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add New Portfolio Item" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a lot less nested ifs, especially when they all do the same result of 'else'.

```
if ( ( $a=3 )
  && ( $b=7 )
  && ($car >= 9)
  && ( $name == 'steve' )
  && ( $more == 'stuff' ) ) {
  // Run stuff here
) else {
  exit('error');
}
```

After your `mysqli_query();` for inserting, run an error check with `mysqli_error($link);` It will tell you of any problems. mysqli_query doesn't return any errors, only 'true' or 'false' depending on how it ran.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is solved. I used concatenation in the query. Here is how my working code looks like(just query) :

```
$qry=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `p_o_r_t_f_o_l_i_o`(`title`,`description`,`duration`,`category`,`image`) values('".$title."','".$description."','".$duration."','".$category."','".$portfolio_img_dir."')");
```

Thanks a lot for everyone who tried to help. Cheers!!